# How do you find a vector in the row space of a matrix that is closest to another vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm hoping to get some theory/background information on how to attempt a problem like this please and thank you:)

Comment: You can think of it as just a least squares problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you say the closest vector, one has to define a notion of distance in which we measure this closedeness. Let it be euclidean norm. Let $b_C$ be the closest vector to $b$. Then

Define $x^*$ as the solution of the problem \begin{align}x^*=\min_{x~\in~R^{M\times 1}}~||Cx-b||_2^2\end{align}

Then $b_c=Cx^*$ is the closest vector to $b$ which lies in the column space of $C$. If you are familiar with a bit of matrix calculus, you can solve the above minimization problem to find $b_c=CC^{\dagger}b$ where $C^{\dagger}$ is the pseudo-inverse. If you are familiar with projection matrices, then projection matrix to the column space of $C$ is given as $P=CC^{\dagger}$ and the closest vector to any given vector $b$ in the column space of $C$ is given as $b_c=Pb$